# Unable to use Capybara, Not sure where I am going wrong 'background' and 'it' etc is not working

Tags: testing, rspec, automated-tests, capybara

Hi I am learning capybara, and i ve tried various answers in SO I am not able to proceed. I am trying to test a application with capybara. Visit is not working, errors out  saying it needs to be within 'it' or example/executable block etc. but with below code , background and scenario etc is not working, execution is not going inside.

Results::

```
C:\Ruby223\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Users/xxx/RubymineProjects/xxx-app/spec/features/xxxxx.rb
"aaa"

Process finished with exit code 0
```

i dont want to mess up the Rails application, so I want a standalone file from where i can execute tests and then integrate with rails app with developers help.

```
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'rspec'



feature "Signing in" do
  p 'aaa'
  background do
    p 'aaa1'
    Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
    end
    Capybara.run_server = false
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
    Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'
  end

  scenario "Signing in with correct credentials" do
    p 'aaa2'
    visit '/q=?alkjaaa'
    within("#session") do
      fill_in 'email', with: 'user@example.com'
      fill_in 'password', with: 'caplin'
    end
    click_button 'Signin'
    expect(page).to have_content 'results'
  end

  given(:other_user) { User.make(email: 'other@example.com', password: 'rous') }

  scenario "Signing in as another user" do
    p 'aaa'
    visit '/sessions/new'
    within("#session") do
      fill_in 'Email', with: other_user.email
      fill_in 'Password', with: other_user.password
    end
    click_button 'Signin'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Invalid email or password'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running that file alone with ruby isn't going to do anything because all it does is define tests, it doesn't execute them.  If you run that file with rspec then it will run the tests defined in the file.

```
rspec your_file.rb
```

Comment: Can you let me know how to set up this in Rubymine run configuraion without changing test scenario name everytime

Comment: @KiulLogoto Sorry, I don't use Rubymine so I have no clue.  Maybe https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.2/using-rspec-in-ruby-projects.html will help